# Issues with viewport size on mobile devices with address bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, viewport

I have a problem that I know is common but I still haven't found any solution. In my html page I have a text at the bottom of the screen. On mobile devices the address bar of the browser makes my 100vh actually longer than the viewport and the writing is therefore hidden. I tried to implement the dvh and svh units but they don't have much compatibility and they are also slow and jerky. I also know that it is not possible to hide the address bar. So I was wondering if it was possible to make this always remain visible, so as to have a defined size of the viewport to work with. In case you think this approach is wrong or that there is better I would be happy to hear what is done in these cases.